# owin Error on first run after installing a customers site umbraco 7 site

Tags: c#, umbraco, owin

I get this error on a 7.3 umbraco build:

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app. -
>   The OwinStartupAttribute.FriendlyName value
>   'UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup' does not match the given value '' in
>   Assembly 'umbraco, Version=1.0.5750.18164, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. - No assembly found containing a Startup or
>   [AssemblyName].Startup class. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add
>   the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in
>   your web.config. To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or
>   Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified
>   startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Any ideas? I've even removed owin.dll from the bin folder and the reference from the solution, also added to the web.config `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />` and still get the same error?

Thanks

Comment: Same here. Did you manage to find an answer @PeteTheGreek...?

Answer (score 5):

If you insert the following web.config appSettings, it should spring to life:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup" />
```

I received this error after upgrading 7.2.8 -> 7.4.1. After performing the above, Umbraco claimed it could not find System.Object. This was resolved by adding the following to the assemblies section:

```
<add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Furthermore; if you receive any dependency mismatches (I received a message that 'umbraco' was attempting to use Microsoft.Owin 2.1.0, despite the latest Umbraco NuGet shipping with 3.0.1.0), you may need to add the following to the assemblyBinding section:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```